# Work and Time Manager in WAS Community Edition

Tags: websphere, application-server, websphere-ce

We were having our application deployed on Websphere Application Server ver 7.x and were using Work and Timer Manager for creating container managed threads and timer respectively.

Now we have to move our application to IBM WebSphere Application Server Community Edition 3.0. During deployment we are facing errors for Work and Time manager entries in our web.xml file. I tried to search on net how to configure these for WASCE but could not find one. I am not even sure that these exists for WASCE or not.

Please inform if there are any resources or you can guide me in correct direction.

The entries in web.xml are as below:

```
<resource-ref id="ResourceRefBinding_tm">
 <res-ref-name>tm/MYApp_TIMERMANAGER</res-ref-name>
 <res-type>commonj.timers.TimerManager</res-type>
 <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
 <res-sharing-scope>Unshareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>

 <resource-ref id="ResourceRefBinding_wm">
      <res-ref-name>wm/MyApp_WORKMANAGER</res-ref-name>
       <res-type>commonj.work.WorkManager</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
      <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
   </resource-ref>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSphere Application Server has proprietary implementation of Timer and Work Manager API. This API is covered by [JSR 237: Work Manager for Application Servers](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=237) that was withdrawn and replaced by [JSR 236: Concurrency Utilities for JavaTM EE](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=236) (part of Java EE 7). The API is not included in WebSphere Application Server Community Edition.

For alternatives to Timer Manager please see [CommonJ TimerManager versus EJB3 TimerService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607101/commonj-timermanager-versus-ejb3-timerservice)

Comment: Thanks fnt...   As i can see from the web.xml file we are using the commonj's Timer are and Work manager.  Have edited the entries above.. To configure it we were using websphere default Work and Time Manager and give the entries in xmi bnd file and web.xml. Is there a similar way to configure the commonj's Time and Work managers with WAS community edition?

Comment: If that was not clear from my answer: Timer and Work Manager API is **not** supported in WAS CE. WAS CE has codebase completely different from "regular" WAS (Apache Geronimo). You should look into alternatives.