# How to configure spring commonj workManager in webSphere liberty profile server 8.5

Tags: java, spring, websphere-liberty, workmanagers, commonj

I'm trying to migrate a spring web application to WebSphere liberty profile 8.5 from WebSphere application server 7. I'm getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: commonj/work/WorkException" at the application start up. I configured the data sources and common libraries using feature manager but couldn't find a way to configure WorkManager.

Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

Here is the exception log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: commonj/work/WorkException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: commonj/work/WorkException
    at com.foo.mytravel.business.TravelBusinessDelegate.<init>(TravelBusinessDelegate.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 31 more
```

Answer (score 2):

The Liberty profile does not support the commonj or asynchbeans programming models.  Instead, it supports the JSR 236 programming model with the [concurrent-1.0 feature](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_config_managedexecutor.html).  You will need to update your application code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. is there anyway I can add the commonj workmanager as a external library to the server and get it work? I cannot change the application code because it is common component shared across different modules. Could you please suggest any workarounds you know of ?

Comment: I'm not aware of a pre-made solution.  In theory, you could probably write an implementation of commonj that uses JSR 236 interfaces.

Comment: @user3767688 There is a standalone implementation of CommonJ - http://commonj.myfoo.de. I have not used it myself. Please also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607101/commonj-timermanager-versus-ejb3-timerservice

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Fixed by adding commonj-twm.jar to application libs.